# Merge Inkscape files without losing the layer information

Tags: merge, inkscape, layers

In Inkscape 1.1.2, how can I merge two Inkscape files without losing the layer information of one of the files? Copy-pasting or importing flattens the inserted image.

Even if I manually, for each layer, copy-paste into a newly created layer in the target file, this will not work, since the relative positioning will not be preserved.

Did I miss an option somehow? Or does Inkscape really not support this? If that's indeed the case can it be done by editing the XML code?

Comment: XML-hacking: Create a simple drawing with the number of layers you'd like to have in the end. May need to have a single object per layer. Save, then pick up the saved file in a text editor and inspect it. You should find the same amount of layer markers as you created layers. Look up the same in your original, then experiment with a copy of that file and one of those you wish to import.

Comment: @Hannu I found the solution. It works by using sublayers, which are not lost when using "Import".

Comment: May I suggest that you write an answer yourself then; note:  `[x] Answer my own question`

Answer (score 1):

Author answered their own question, I'm copying it here for the record since it was helpful for me.

1. Go to the smaller file, create a new layer and make every other layer a sublayer of this by drag and drop and save it
2. Go to the larger file, create a new placeholder layer. Import the smaller file (`File -> import`)
3. Move the inner layer from the file out and delete the placeholder layer